# jQuery: append multiple elements

Tags: jquery, for-loop, append

I'm drying to dynamically add line items depending on the value of "n"; jQuery will only append it once, even though the loop runs multiple times.

Suggestions on how to append "n" number of line items?

```
var t = $(this);
var counter = $("<ol class='slide-counter'></ol>");
var dot = $("<li></li>");

if (n > 1) {
    t.append(counter);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        counter.append(dot);
    }
    $(".slide-counter li:first-child").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: `counter.append(dot.clone());`. If you pass `.append` a Dom/JQuery element, it will simply reposition it.

Comment: can you post your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a 'new' element each time, you can do this by moving dot into the for loop

```
var t = $(this);
var counter = $("<ol class='slide-counter'></ol>");

if (n > 1) {
    t.append(counter);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var dot = $("<li></li>");
        counter.append(dot);
    }
    $(".slide-counter li:first-child").addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to turn dot into a string, otherwise you're trying to add a unique element to it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help. Ninsly's suggestion made it work, but DaveB's answer also worked.

Here is what I ended up using...

```
var t = $(this);
var counter = $("<ol class='slide-counter'></ol>");
var dot = $("<li></li>");

if (n > 1) {
    t.append(counter);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        counter.append(dot.clone());
    }
    $(".slide-counter li:first-child").addClass("active");
}
```